# Do you lose VS Code files and settings when installing Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code 1.73.1 on a new Windows 11 laptop a couple weeks ago and installed around 25 extensions and played around with it a bit. Today I uninstalled McAfee and installed Norton virus protection and then installed Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.4.2. Now I find that all my VS Code work and extensions are gone. The .vscode folder is empty aside from an empty extensions folder and the single file argv.json.

I am assuming the swap of McAfee for Norton is not at fault here. I expected that installing Visual Studio would not have any effect on VS Code extensions, workspaces and configuration. Even if I accidentally reinstalled VS Code I would not expect the extensions, configuration, etc. to be cleared. Has anyone else installed VS Code and then Visual Studio and experienced similar loss?

Comment: Please [edit] to describe precisely what files are now gone. Distinguish between user-scoped files and workspace-scoped files.